# How to introduce tests in an underway Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, project

I'm using eclipse in a Java environment. I have to introduce testing to an already underway project. How to start? Unit tests on the classes, and what else? What are the best tools for the job (considering I'm using eclipse)? TestNG, JUnit, JTiger?

How do I make others adapt themselves to use the tests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a great support of JUnit. This looks like a great starting point. I would add a new source directory test and create a package structure mirroring your src folder. Then you can add your unit tests one by one. Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking of using JUnit since it comes with Eclipse, but didn't want to lose time in case it was a bad decision. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Unless your team already is used to writing tests, testing all old components is not really feasible (sometimes not even then), as writing testable software requires a specific mentality.

I think, the best time to start writing tests is when you can define some new component that is critical enough to warrant the extra effort, but somehow new, so the already existing code base would not be tested as much.

This way you could find a testing approach, identify the benefits and learning the mentality without putting too much effort in something that might not work for your team.

About tooling: I sadly cannot really compare the different tools, as I only have experience with JUnit.

JUnit is easy to start with, as the corresponding tooling is already included in Eclipse (wizards to create templates, running and evaluation options...), and there are plenty of documentation and examples available on the net.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit and TestNG are both fine. TestNG has more capabilities and can be helpful with integration tests, JUnit is more focused on unit tests.

You may want to get acquainted with some kind of mocking library like Mockito. Code coverage tools like Cobertura and continuous integration tools like Jenkins are great too.

Using a DI framework like Spring or Guice is helpful for writing more easily-testable code. Whether you use a DI framework or not, the more loosely-coupled your code the easier it is to test. Since your project is already under way it is probably too late for this part, which will make your task harder.

It can be very hard to get co-workers to cooperate with testing. You may want to introduce it selectively on pieces where it can make the most difference. Writing tests for already-finished functionality is usually painful and a waste of time. Tests should be small, have few dependencies, be understandable, and should run quickly. The more painful it is to write tests, run the tests, and fix broken tests, the more resistance you will get.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good questions.

If your project does not tests at all and already underway you should introduce the tests incrementally. When you have to develop a new feature write test for this feature, classes that you are going to change and features that could be broken. The same is when you are fixing bugs. First write test that reproduces the bug, then fix it.

I used JUnit and TestNG. Both are almost the same. TestNG has groups, i.e. you can mark test to be belong to group like development, build, integration, etc. This is mostly relevant if you have a lot of tests and it takes significant time to run them all.

Do you already have automatic build? If not start from this. If you prefer to use maven it is relatively simple.  When your build is ready write a couple of unit tests (just to have something to fail...)
Then install Hudson/Jenkins and define your project there. People will see how cool is it that once you commit your new code the build runs almost immediately and you see all failed tests. Probably try to show the strength of TDD to your boss and try to explain him that he should force all team members to write tests.

If you have enough energy introduce Sonar to your company. People will see how awful the code that they are writing and how poor the test coverage is. The they will see how quickly the test coverage is growing up and will probably invest more into unit testing.

Shortly, good luck. You are on the right way.

Comment: Just as a comment, my workteam has Jenkins as a CI tool. I think it'll benefit everyone in the long run. Thanks!